# NetSuite REST Services - Company Address

Tags: rest, netsuite

I am working on external application to pull data from NetSuite using NetSuite's REST services.
Unable to find the way to pull Company Address.
Please respond if you the way.

Answer (score 0):

The Company's address would be present in NetSuite's Company Information section (i.e navigate to Setup --> Company --> Company Information). 
If you are using a NetSuite Restlet script to pull Company address, you need to use "N/config" module.

**So using the N/config module, load the company information record:**

```
var companyInfo = config.load({
    type: config.Type.COMPANY_INFORMATION
}); 

// then get value of Company address

var companyAddress = companyInfo.getValue({
    fieldId: 'mainaddress_text'
});

return companyAddress;       // return the address in Restlet script
```

Hope this helps.